# Entity Framework and MySql Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am working with Entity Framework 4.0, VS 2010, MySql server database, and mysql-connector-net-6.4.4 for connection purpose. It works fine, that said, it can generate Model classes, csdl, ssdl etc files well. But, for stored procedures it doesn't work.

Here is what happens..

Right clicked on an SP from Model Browser, select [Add Function Import]. This opened a dialog box
Filled appropriate values like, Function Import Name, Stored Procedure Name
Click on [Get Column Information]. This results into some Grid filled up at the bottom of this button. In the grid, there is a column named [EDM Type]. This column shows [Not supported] due to some unknown reason :(
Now, clicked on [Create New Complex Type]. This goes OK, without Error
Now, clicked on OK button
After doing all above steps, there is no Complex Type created in the code however, which is the problem.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Do you see the complex type in the `Complex Types` folder in the Model part of the Model Browser?

Comment: Is this the answer? If not, can you specify the problem in code?

Comment: @Mentoliptus I created a complex type and i see it in the Complex type folder. All what i have written was calling the procedure:
var info = ctx.GetAllEmployees().ToList();
gridview1.datasource = info;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated `Complex Type` is in the `Complex Types` folder in the Model part of the Model Browser.

To access ti in code, use it as any other Entity

```
MyComplexType ct = new MyComplexType();
```

And you can use it as a result type for your stored procedure:

```
List<MyComplexType> info = ctx.GetAllEmployees().ToList<MyComplexType>();
```

You must ensure that the `GridView`'s columns mappings match the `Complex Type`'s properties, or that the `GridView`'s property `AutoGenerateColumns` is set to true.

Comment: An HttpException exception is thrown:
The data source for GridView with id 'GridView1' did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns.  Ensure that your data source has content.

Comment: @AhmedSalah Yes, I know that an exception will be thrown if your `GridView` doesn't have the column mappings that match the Complex Type's properties. You must ensure that in code or markup.

Comment: When performing the previous steps using SQL Server the code runs without problems. I think there is a bug in mysql .NET connector in mapping stored procedures with EF

Comment: and what a bout if my data grid is to be bound to many data sources??

Comment: @AhmedSalah The question about the data grid and many data sources is a separate question. Please mark my answer as accepted answer if it helped solve your first question.

Comment: the case now is i do not want to configure the data grid to map to any of stored procedure return

Comment: Just curious, how will I access a property of MyComplextType if there is none created in EDMX?